# Trouble installing emacs 26.3 Red Hat

Tags: install, emacs26

Followed these steps:

- Downloaded emacs-26.3.tar.gz, drop it in a subdir of my home dir
- cd to there
- tar -xvf emacs-26.1.tar.xz
- Seems happy a bunch of files appear
- cd emacs-26.3
- ./configure --prefix=/home/<my_home_dir>/.local/share/emacs --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no --with-x-toolkit=no --with-jpeg=no --with-png=no --with-gnutls=no

Config errors saying
The required function 'tputs' was not found in any library and it lists the 5 libs it tried.

libtinfo libnurses libterminfo libcurses libtermcap

- ran >sudo apt install for those five and it errors saying
  unable to locate package.

It looks like sudo can't find them.

I don't have public internet on the machine I am installing on

Comment: Are you sure configure ran happily? After I run configure, the Makefile has been created

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was missing ncurses.
Ran sudo apt install ncurses-dev and config runs well enough to generate a make file.

I still needed the --with-xxx=no options for all of those graphics packages as part of running configure.

Then was able to run make and have emacs 26.3 up now